# How to change point size in Scatter Chart?

Tags: java, css, javafx, plot, scatter-plot

I have this `ScatterChart` made in JavaFX:
[image: Bifurcation diagram]
How can I set the data points size?

I found that it should be done in CSS, but even having the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#xychart), I still cannot figure it out.

Comment: Not sure, but [nice graph](http://interzone.com/~cheung/Page.dir/pg.metaworld4.html).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Yay, thanks. But imagine trying to plot [this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e7/HenonMap_BifurcationDiagram.png) using those huge points.

Comment: FWIW I would not use the Chart API for something like that second image (or even maybe the first one). Consider a Canvas or perhaps WritableImage for something like that.

Comment: @James_D just for completeness - I ended up with [this](http://i.imgur.com/CpOea19.jpg) using `WritableImage` for sin(x). Too bad there is a bug preventing from generating super high resolution images. Meh.

Comment: With the Chart API, every point is an independent node, complete with CSS settings, etc. These nodes are pretty expensive both in terms of memory and in terms of the time it takes to render them. So for this kind of application the performance of the Chart API simply won't be good enough for what you're trying to do here, even if you could get the resolution you needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```css
.chart-symbol {
    -fx-background-radius: 10px ;
    -fx-padding: 10px ;
}
```

If you need this to apply just to a specific chart, give the chart an id and use the id in the CSS file:

```
chart.setId("bifurcation-diagram");
```

```css
#bifurcation-diagram .chart-symbol {
    -fx-background-radius: 10px ;
    -fx-padding: 10px ;
}
```

SSCCE:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.ScatterChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Data;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Series;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ScatterChartExample extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        ScatterChart<Number, Number> chart = new ScatterChart<>(new NumberAxis(), new NumberAxis());

        chart.setId("bifurcation-diagram");

        Series<Number, Number> series = new Series<>();
        chart.getData().add(series);

        for (int i = 0 ; i <= 100; i++) {
            double lambda = 4.0 * i / 100 ;
            double x = 0.5 ;
            for (int j = 0 ; j < 100 ; j++) {
                x = lambda * x * (1-x);
            }
            for (int j = 0 ; j < 50; j++) {
                series.getData().add(new Data<>(lambda, x));
                x = lambda * x * (1-x);
            }
        }

        Scene scene = new Scene(chart, 1200, 800);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("bifurcation.css");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

bifurcation.css:

```css
#bifurcation-diagram .chart-symbol {
    -fx-background-radius: 10px ;
    -fx-padding: 10px ;
}
```

[image]

If you want smaller points, this doesn't seem to work well (I assume because they are not compatible with the default node generated for the chart data). In this case you might need to set the node for the data as well:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i <= 400; i++) {
    double lambda = 1.0 * i / 100 ;
    double x = 0.5 ;
    for (int j = 0 ; j < 100 ; j++) {
        x = lambda * x * (1-x);
    }
    for (int j = 0 ; j < 50; j++) {
        Data<Number, Number> data = new Data<>(lambda, x);
        Region plotpoint = new Region();
        plotpoint.setShape(new Circle(0.5));
        data.setNode(plotpoint);
        series.getData().add(data);
        x = lambda * x * (1-x);
    }
}
```

and the CSS

```css
#bifurcation-diagram .chart-symbol {
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
    -fx-padding: 1px ;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to increase the size of all points, you can simply use following CSS:

```
.chart-symbol {
    -fx-padding: 10px;
}
```

By the way, this is an example from [*JavaFX: Working with JavaFX UI Components (scatter chart section)*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/scatter-chart.htm):

```
.default-color5.chart-symbol {
    -fx-background-color: #860061, white;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 2;
    -fx-background-radius: 5px;
    -fx-padding: 5px;
}
```

It makes a fifth series symbol a hollow circle. Please see the relation between `.default-color<x>` in this stylesheet and CSS Reference Guide mentioned below - it's really easy.

More detailed info can be found at [JavaFX CSS Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#scatterchart) in Scatter Chart section.