# Force relayout of Java FX Chart programatically

Tags: java, javafx, charts

I have made programmatic changes to a Java FX Line Chart and I need a programmatic way to force a re-layout of the JavaFX Chart to occur.  This question has been asked/answered before but not in my context.

I have tried the typical methods that have been presented as answers to this question (see complete, minimal example code below with in-line attempts at solving the problem).  None of the typical solutions to this problem work.

Specifically (sp is a StackPane):

```
    sp.requestLayout(); // does not work
```

and

```
    sp.applyCss(); 
    sp.layout();        // does not work
```

placing the above code in a `.runLater()` does not work.

I know that my changes are present in the chart because
(1) When I resize the chart by hand my changes suddenly appear
(2) When I use the "resize" method programmatically my changes appear BUT there is a different error (plus only parent nodes are supposed to use the "resize" method - not us programmers).

Below is a minimal complete set of code which reproduces the problem.  When you run the code I programmatically change one of the data points to be larger when the chart is displayed. This resize works correctly.  When you right-click on the chart a context menu appears with one choice ("Resize ALL the points").  When you select that single option my code resizes all the points - BUT - none of the data points are resized visually.  If I resize the chart manually by dragging a side, the chart does a re-layout and all the data node sizes immediately visually change to the correct size (The size I programmatically set them to).

How can I force the re-layout to occur programmatically that I can force to occur manually?  I would NOT like to do a hack (like programmatically set the stage size to be 1 pixel smaller and then set it one pixel larger).

Note: I have read that attempts to do a `requestLayout()` while a layout is in progress will be ignored so perhaps something like that is going on.  I think a `requestLayout()` inside of a `runLater()` would fix the issue of an ongoing Layout() but that has not worked either.

**Update:** Scaling was suggested as an alternative to changing the StackPane size.  This solution may be helpful to some but not to me.  The Look and Feel of scaling a symbol is different than the look and feel of changing the regions size and allowing the "symbol" to grow into that size.

As a complete aside this is my first stackoverflow post. So thanks for all the previous examples a I have used from this forum in the past & thanks in advance for the answer to this problem.

```
import java.util.Random;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart.SortingPolicy;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Data;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Series;
import javafx.scene.control.ContextMenu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseButton;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class dummy  extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Random random = new Random();
        final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
        final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        xAxis.setLabel("X");
        yAxis.setLabel("Y");
        final LineChart<Number,Number> lineChart = new LineChart<Number,Number>(xAxis,yAxis);   

        Series<Number,Number> series = new Series<Number,Number>();
        series.setName("Dummy Data");
        // Generate data
        double x = 0.0;     
        double y = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Data<Number,Number> data  = new Data(x += random.nextDouble(), y+=random.nextDouble());
            series.getData().add(data);
        }
        lineChart.getData().add(series);
        lineChart.setTitle("Random Data");
        lineChart.setAxisSortingPolicy(SortingPolicy.NONE); 

        Scene scene = new Scene(lineChart,1200,600);

        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        // This resizes the first data point directly (this resize is displayed correctly when program is run)
        Node node = series.getData().get(0).getNode();
        setSize((StackPane)node,20);

        // The context menu is invoked by a right click on the line Chart.  It will resize the data point based on a context menu pick
        // this resize does not work....unless I resize the window manually which causes a refresh/re-layout of the chart).
        lineChart.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                if (MouseButton.SECONDARY.equals(mouseEvent.getButton())) {
                    Scene scene = ((Node)mouseEvent.getSource()).getScene();
                    ContextMenu menu = createMenu(lineChart);
                    menu.show(scene.getWindow(), mouseEvent.getScreenX(), mouseEvent.getScreenY());
                }  
            }
        });
    }

    private void setSize(StackPane sp, int size) {
        sp.setMinSize(size, size);
        sp.setMaxSize(size, size);
        sp.setPrefSize(size, size);
    }
    // this creates a context menu that will allow you to resize all the data point nodes
    private ContextMenu createMenu(LineChart<Number,Number> lineChart) {

        final ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();

        final MenuItem resize = new MenuItem("Resize ALL the points");
        resize.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                for (Series<Number, Number> series : lineChart.getData()) {
                    for (Data<Number, Number> data : series.getData()) {
                        StackPane sp = (StackPane)data.getNode();
                        setSize (sp, 20);
                        // The above resizes do not take effect unless/until I manually resize the chart.

                        // the following two calls do not do anything;
                        sp.applyCss();
                        sp.layout();

                        // The request to layout the node does nothing
                        sp.requestLayout();

                        // Doing both of the above as runLaters does nothing
                        Platform.runLater(()->{sp.applyCss();sp.layout();});
                        Platform.runLater(()->{sp.requestLayout();});

                        // Going after the parent does nothing either
                        Group group = (Group)sp.getParent();
                        group.applyCss();
                        group.layout();
                        group.requestLayout();

                        // Going after the parent in a run later does nothing
                        Platform.runLater(()->{
                            group.applyCss();
                            group.layout();
                            group.requestLayout();
                        });

                        // note... doing a resize [commented out below] will work-ish.
                        // The documentation says NOT to use it thought that as it is for internal use only.
                        // By work-ish, the data points are enlarged BUT they are no longer centered on the data point
                        // When I resize the stage they get centered again - so this "solves" my original problem but causes a different problem
                        ////////////////////////////////////
                        //  sp.resize(20, 20);            // Uncomment this line to see how it mostly works but introduces a new issue
                        ////////////////////////////////////
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        contextMenu.getItems().add(resize);
        return contextMenu;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Add a dummy style sheet `lineChart.getStylesheets().add("");` after the `for` loops ended does the trick. It is a bit hackish. so I don't particularly  like it. I hope  a better one will come up.

Comment: looks like a bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force a relayout by using e.g. an inner class

```
  class LineChartX<X, Y> extends LineChart<X, Y>
  {
    public LineChartX(@NamedArg("xAxis") Axis<X> xAxis, @NamedArg("yAxis") Axis<Y> yAxis)
    {
      super(xAxis, yAxis);
    }

    @Override
    public void layoutPlotChildren()
    {
      super.layoutPlotChildren();
    }
  }
```

and calling

```
lineChart.layoutPlotChildren();
```

in your menu action.

**Simple one-line Solution:**

nodes in LineChart scene graph have these parent-child relationships:
Pane chartContent - Group plotArea - Group plotContent - Path seriesLine;

layout requests for Group plotArea, defined in class XYChart, are suppressed:

```
private final Group plotArea = new Group(){
  @Override public void requestLayout() {} // suppress layout requests
};
```

but Pane chartContent accepts layout requests:

```
Node node = series.getNode();
if (node instanceof Path) {
  Path seriesLine = (Path) node;
  Parent parent = seriesLine.getParent();
  if (parent instanceof Group) {
    Group plotContent = (Group) parent;
    parent = plotContent.getParent();
    if (parent instanceof Group) {
      Group plotArea = (Group) parent;
      parent = plotArea.getParent();
      if (parent instanceof Pane) {
        Pane chartContent = (Pane) parent;
        chartContent.requestLayout();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

so relayout of your chart can be forced by addding this single line

```
series.getNode().getParent().getParent().getParent().requestLayout();
```

to the end of your menu action handler.

Comment: Basically you extended the LineChart class and made the "protected" call `layoutPlotChildren()` "public". I placed the now public call after my for loop and it worked perfectly.   What I like about this solution is that you can create an instance of the extended class using a factory method and yet just return a LineChart object.  You can treat this LineChart object as a LineChart object everywhere hiding its true nature.  Then in this routine you can cast it back to a LineChartX and call its now public `layoutPlotChildren()`.  The only compromise/cheat is using a factory method to begin with!

Comment: Note: as a caution to others I don't think this solution will work with JavaFX modules.  I believe a reflection-based approach that also gains access to the `layoutPlotChildren()` method will also work.  Basically this solution and a reflection based solution is breaking the defined encapsulation of Java FX (which would not be needed if the Java FX designers did not overly restrict access)

Comment: @kleopatra,they don't.  I was in error and misremembering issues I've had with modules and private variables/methods and I confused the two.   Thanks for catching the error. 
As an explanation I've had issues where a member was private and subclassing didn't gain you access.  I did the split packages trick and copied the code and got access to the private member that way.  This trick does not work with modules which dis-allow split packages.  My rule of thumb was "can't gain access to private members in modules (except via reflection)".  `LayoutPlotChildren()` is protected - so no issues.

Comment: I am accepting the **Simple Solution** part of the @kuleis answer as the best answer.  It is simple (a 1 liner).  It is direct (it uses a `requestLayout()` call which is appropriate).  It is specific (it is based on a Series versus being based on the LineChart as a whole).  It included an explanation as to why it works and why other approaches using `requestLayout()` at lower levels in the parent child tree were not working.  Note: It could fail at some future time if Java FX internals change but the underlying strategy/approach could be likely reused if that occurred.

Comment: my nice (and upvote) was for the original, reverted

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to cast that node into a StackPane and set sizes. You need to use the `setScaleX()` and `setScaleY()` Methods

```
    Node node = series.getData().get(0).getNode();
    node.setScaleX(20);
    node.setScaleY(20);

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        for (Series<Number, Number> series : lineChart.getData()) {
            for (Data<Number, Number> data : series.getData()) {
                Node node = data.getNode();
                node.setScaleY(20);
                node.setScaleX(20);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Using `ScaleX` and `Scale Y` solves a different problem with a different look and feel then what was requested.  Several types of changes to the StackPane (including your solution... scaling) will take effect immediately.  My changes to the StackPane size will not.  A programmatic solution that causes the changes to the Stack Pane Size to take effect immediately is the solution I am looking for. +'s for the Quick response!

Answer (score 0):

@c0der posted a solution in comment form to my original post which worked but produced a runtime warning (in Eclipse).  His solution was to add a dummy style sheet at the lineChart level with `lineChart.getStylesheets().add("");` after the for loops ended.   This code produced the warning "Apr 28, 2020 9:01:12 AM com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager loadStylesheetUnPrivileged WARNING: Resource "" not found."

What did work without causing a run-time warning was to load an empty .css file and add it as a StyleSheet:

`lineChart.getStylesheets().add(CSS.class.getResource("Empty.css").toExternalForm()); 
    // note: I keep my .css resource files at the same location as my CSS class
    // which is why I have the code "CSS.class" above`

This one line solution worked once but I doubted it would work multiple times.  I tested it to by increasing the size of the StackPane by 5 for each successive time "Resize ALL the points" was selected (in my dummy code above).  Sure enough, it only worked the first time.

However, I added the no-op code `lineChart.getStylesheets().replaceAll((s)->s+" ");` before that one line solution and now it works multiple times in a row.
No matter how many times I executed the two lines of code

```
lineChart.getStylesheets().replaceAll((s)->s+" ");
lineChart.getStylesheets().add(CSS.class.getResource("Empty.css").toExternalForm()); `
```

it (1) worked and (2) The size of the list of lineChart StyleSheets did not grow beyond a size of 1. So a solution with a mystery.

Note: if you have an existing style sheet (I did not in my dummy example above) `lineChart.getStylesheets().replaceAll((s)->s+" ");` by itself may work as well.  For some reason `lineChart.getStylesheets().replaceAll((s)->s);` without adding the " " on the end did not work.

Note: I originally thought I would have to code up a toggle solution to add Empty.css and the remove Empty.css with alternate calls but that proved unnecessary.

**Bottom Line:** if you have an existing StyleSheet `lineChart.getStylesheets().replaceAll((s)->s+" ");` works.  If you do not have an existing StyleSheet adding an empty .css file as a StyleSheet in conjunction with the above replaceAll works.

Thanks again to @c0der for his original approach.

Comment: I did propose this hackish solution but I am not fond of it. If you add css resources consider using them to [change the size of the data points](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39947689/3992939)

Comment: Thanks @c0der.  A css only approach was not appealing.  I have 18 symbols that at run time can be resized, recolored, and filled or not.  The 18 symbols are in .css but many are not square and use specific css paddings (ex 4x, 7x, 4x, 7x) to keep their shapes.  These paddings are size specific.  With 20 sizes per symbol I would have 18*20 css symbol definitions (or I change css settings at run-time based on a size multiplier).  My non css sizing works UNTIL I placed the sizing code under the context menu where a Java FX bug broke the approach.  Hence my question as to how to force a layout.